# My js game constantly allocates and releases memory

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome-devtools, pixi.js

Something wrong is happening with my pixi.js game. It allocated 1MB a second and 3 seconds later GS releases it. And so on, infinitely.

Of course I read this, but it seems like Chrome Tools are unable to detect a problem - when I record the Allocation Timeline - it shows some rare spikes, which, when selected - show some functions, but also there are constant tiny spikes of memory allocation, which don't show anything. I select them, and in a list of functions I see nothing!

In my frame by frame code I optimized everything - when I turn off pixi - the memory doesn't move. Only when I do the pixi render the scene on every frame - then this constant allocation/release starts and never ends. On PC it's ok, but on mobile every 10 seconds it freezes for 5 seconds - impossible to play.

Did anybody encounter frequent allocations/GC in their code? If yes - how did you debug it, how did you fix it?

Comment: Well ...rendering takes memory. Thats how it is.

Comment: If you have heavy calculations, move those to a webworker. Then use postmessage to get gamestate updates. It allows you to seperate game thread from rendering thread.

Comment: It's unclear what kind of help you expect given your problem statement. We have *no* idea what your code is doing, where, when, how, nothing.

Comment: You're having a game. a game has heavy calculations. collision detection, entity updates, sprite movements, game events, ray tracing, projectile arc calculations, etc... all those combined can end up pretty heavy, causing a lot of local variables moving in and out of scoped functions. 1mb of data is a LOT, which implies heavy calculations. This will be caused by the calculations for rendering. Seperating game thread form rendering thread would free up some computation time.

Comment: I expect that in case if anyone encountered such a problem, anyone had problems with frequent allocations and GC - how did he debug it? You don't need code for that, do you.

Comment: Usually in a game you have a game thread and a rendering thread. In javascript the rendering thread is the main scope, where you have access to the document and window object. The game thread goes into a webworker, and updates the game states and pushes updates to the rendering thread, who updates the canvas/whatever. That way they can run in parralel and don't need to wait for eachother. Usually game threads run in like 50ms ticks/iterations or shorter, depending on amount of work. Then it's simply debugging either the one or the other. depending if it's a graphics, or gamestate issue.

Comment: Shal, people are trying to help you. [Be nice.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: Maybe an idea, but have you tried coding your game with three.js instead of pixy.js? I've tried some samples by pixy.js and they seem to me and the beast of the pc I have very under performing compared to three.js. The pixy.js causes a lot of stutters and hangs when something else in the DOM updates something. And try to implement webworkers. just a suggestion.

Comment: @Kolors, in which way I am not nice, tell me? :) If you mean that I said to Tschallacka that "what are you talking about, did you read the question". As you see, he didn't see it as something bad, but as a question, where I want to know what is he talking about. And by "did you read the question" I meand exactly that. As you see, he replies and actually explains what he is talking about, which is great and helpful. It's because he has a healthy self esteem. If someone wants to get offended - he'll find the way - so it's not about him. So what do you mean Kolors, maybe anything else?

Comment: At this moment there is a lot of disucssion going on on meta.stackoverflow.com about being nice and such because of a blogpost. I don't tend to care that much. Let's not debate meta issues on this post but keep it on topic.

Comment: @Tschallacka, actually you are right, pixi creates dom objects to test cross origin for textures, even when it's not needed at all. So I guess your advice to try three.js seems very plausible. I'll try this and will report here. If it doesn't help - will try your worker separation idea. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience Pixi.js has a GC spikes even with empty scene, you can test it yourself. Feel free to open github issue in their repo. I believe they had some discussions about leaks already. But I don't think pixi itself should impact that much, unless you have thousands and thousands of objects.

Are you sure you did everything? You should abuse Object pool pattern and pre-allocations in you code. This is especially true when you need to constantly create/delete objects (Something like bullets).
General information
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/static-mem-pools/

Upd:
For debugging chrome tools is pretty much okay.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/

Comment: Exactly! my game contains no more than 100 DisplayObjects. I always use pools, in all my projects. In this particular game all objects created before game evnn starts, after that I never do "new" during the game! And furthermore, when **nothing** happens, the game is still, nothing changes on the screen at all, I turned off all my activity (except for pixi render() on every frame) - and despite all that it eats 1M/sec and collects garbage all the time... And of course, that "chrome dev tools/memory problems" was the first thing I read and tried everything from there many times in many ways